# How to fetch last 2 minutes data from mysql using Java

Tags: java, mysql, api

I need to retrieve last 2 min data from MySQL database using Java Program? I don't know how to write a query to fetch data in particular time interval and referred a lot but I didn't find the correct query? can any one please help me out ?

Below is my Java program which connected to MySQL database, it is having query but that query is not working and throws SQLSyntaxErrorException.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String qry = "SELECT * FROM test.api WHERE EndTime = SELECT max(time) - interval 2 minute";

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";

        String user = "root";

        String password = "root@123";

        Connection conn = null;
        try 
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(qry);

            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                String Name = rs.getString("Name");
                String time = rs.getString("EndTime");

                System.out.println(time);
                System.out.println(Name);
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(conn != null)
            {
                try 
                {
                    conn.close();
                    System.out.println("---Connection closed successfully---");
                } 
                catch (SQLException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use max(time) Instead use now()

```
String qry = "SELECT * FROM test.api WHERE EndTime = date_sub(now(), interval 2 minute)";
```

Comment: I have a doubt that now() takes the current time of the system. Is it correct ?

Comment: what time will you insert in to the db? current time of the system? or current time of server?

Comment: @Srinivas now() does, clear your doubt; see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/944).

Comment: @VijayaVigneshKumar your answer is not correct. The OP wants all the data in the past two minutes.

Comment: @cdaiga Yeah... i'm just spliting the time for last 2 minutes data

Comment: but you use `=` instead of `>=`.

Comment: @VijayaVigneshKumar  The data inserted in the database is server time not the system time. In this case what I want to do to fetch 2 min data ?

Comment: Hi srinivas the above query is correct only... but it taken the seconds to compare so only you didn't getting desire result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-- suppose your data source time coincides with your storage server time
-- so to get the time 2 minutes ago should be like
SELECT * FROM test.api WHERE EndTime >= now() - interval 2 minute;

-- suppose your data source time is 60 behind your storage server time
-- so to get the time 2 minutes ago should be like
SELECT * FROM test.api WHERE EndTime >= now() - interval (2 + 60) minute;

-- suppose your data source time is 60 infront of your storage server time
-- so to get the time 2 minutes ago should be like
SELECT * FROM test.api WHERE EndTime >= now() - interval (2 - 60) minute;
```

So you would have to know the time difference between both times and used the appropriate query as proposed above.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/19522)

Answer (score 0):

```
     String qry = "SELECT * FROM test.api WHERE EndTime > date_sub(now(),interval 2 MINUTE) ";
```